# Stop calling onDestroy method after pressing the home button in Nexus 7" tab

Tags: android

I am getting a problem since last two days.Actually when i run my app in any other device except the nexus tab,after pressing the home button the onDestroy() method not called.Its fine for me but when the same app is run in nexus tab the onDestroy() method is called after pressing the home button.What i want, i don't want to call onDestroy() method in nexus 7 after pressing the home button.Please sort out my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Don't rely on `onDestroy()` being called. You should do everything you need in `onPause()` instead.

From the [onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) docs:

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get to decide that. As soon as your app goes into `onPause` Android can reclaim the resources used by your app by killing your app and going through `onDestroy`. You need to override the lifecycle events and handle saving the data necessary within them to prevent this.

Comment: actually i want to alive my activity after being pressed the home button

Comment: You can't make sure that your activity will stay "alive" when entering the home screen. It is completely up to android in which state the activity will be kept. If you need to perform operations, make use of a Service.